# SKPhysicsBody doesn't work on custom class for SKSpriteNode

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode9

I wont use a "custom class"  on interface builder for an example "Walls".

Drag a SpriteNode and set the custom class : Wall.

On code Wall.swift :

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
}

func setup() {
    self.color = .white // This works

    let body = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: frame.size)

    body.isDynamic = true
    body.allowsRotation = false
    body.pinned = false
    body.affectedByGravity = true

    body.friction = 0.0
    body.restitution = 0.0
    body.linearDamping = 1.0
    body.angularDamping = 1.0

    body.mass = 1.0
    body.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    body.density = 1.0
    body.charge = 1.0

    body.categoryBitMask = 4294967295
    body.collisionBitMask = 4294967295
    body.fieldBitMask = 4294967295
    body.contactTestBitMask = 0

    self.physicsBody = body
}
```

The sprite change color to white, but physicsBody doesn't work.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: How do you know it is not working

Comment: I would also put a print log in the setup function to verify that is getting called.

Comment: Please run the code, in debug everything it's ok, but physicsBody probably be nil before? i don't know. In game the node don't have a physicsBody (don't collide, rotate, pin, gravity, etc..) and don't shows with "showPhysics" on true @SkylerLauren Knight0fDragon

Comment: Did you try putting a log in the setup() func as I mentioned? If it doesn't print  odds are you didn't specify the right class when you dragged it into the editor or you are not subclassing the correct class.

Comment: yes, debug it's ok, line self.color = .white change color and body is setup, but in game run time body doesn't appear @SkylerLauren

Comment: Only other thing to check is what frame.size is. I don’t think SKSpriteNode has a frame so not entirely sure where that is coming from. It should just be size in most cases. No need for frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read the `SKScene` that contains your custom `SKSpriteNode`, the `SKPhysicBody` is also read, and overwrites what you have put in your initialization function. You must therefore put your `SKPhysicBody` after the `SKScene` has been read, for example in the `awakeFromNib` function.